# How to remove index.php from a tag or archive page URL in the root blog?

Tags: multisite, permalinks

I'm developing a Multisite where the root site is an agregator (using the mu-sitewide-tags plugin). I created a custom widget to show tags across all sites, but when I click on the tag page on the main blog, it loads like this:

http://example.com/index.php/tag/name_of_the_tag/

I tried to remove it creating a custom permalink, but wordpress doesn't allow to take it off.

Is that possible to do it? Any idea?

Comment: Are you on a Windows or Linux hosting?

Comment: I'm using a Linux hosting

Comment: Could i have a look at your .htaccess file contents?

Comment: Im using Nginx to deal with the rewrite rules, but it is basically like this one: http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx#WordPress_Multisite_Subdirectory_rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to flush your permalink structure that might be the issue

Comment: **INCREDIBLE! It worked!** 

Do you know what happens to wordpress act like this?!?!?!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the permalinks as a Superadmin in the network admin area.